# function seems to access the last reference of a variable instead of storing it in the function call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was going to write this to be long and complicated, but i figured to go to the straight forward approach.

I have a loop that creates an array of elements where the variable **Url**.  The array looks like this:

```
 x = [url,function(){...},function(){...}];
```

and then into an arrayList:

```
 arrayList = [x1,x2,x3,x4,x5];
```

I figure that makes sense so far.  It stores in the arrayList object, 1 var and 2 functions.

Here is the kicker.

When i iterate through arrayList, **url** is all the same, the last reference to **url** in the forloop that created the arraylist.

My attempt to solve this was, doing a .toString() on the variable to store the contents of it in the array, instead of the variable name itself.  *that didnt work :(*

What would i do to resolve this?  im stumped :-(

**Edit:  I want to show what the loop looks like because 1 of the answers was about the array inaccurately referencing it**

**Edit2:  The url which is causing issues, is the inner url, in displayFile below.  It seems those are all pointing to the same reference, which is a nono.  How would i go about changing those?  Would i have to pass it in as a parameter???**

```
var newArray = new Array();
for(var i=0;i<fileUrls.length;++i) {
   var url = fileUrls[i];
   var x = [];//new Array();
   x = [url,
    function(){
       displayFile(url, 'image', null, ft_id, null, null, null, null, !MA.isiOS());
    }, 
    function(e){
    if(DEBUG) console.log('Error creating gallery thumbnail');
    alert('There was a problem creating a thumbnail');
    MA.hideMessage();
    }
];
newArray.push(x);
}
```

Comment: If you're constructing those functions in the loop, and the functions internally refer to "url", they're all referring to the same variable. Constructing a function with a reference to an "outer" variable does **not** "freeze" the value of the variable. It remains a "live" reference to the variable in the outer scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I think that you have is rather:

```
arrayList = [x,x,x,x,x];
```

I.e. an array that contains a number of references to the same object. If that is the case, then when you look at the `url` property in the different items, you are looking at the same property all the time, because it's the same item over and over.

That would be the result of reusing the array to populate the `arrayList` array, for example:

```
var x = [];
var arrayList = [];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  x[0] = 'url ' + i;
  x[1] = function(){};
  x[2] = function(){};
  arrayList.push(x);
}
```

The solution would be to create a new array in each iteration:

```
var arrayList = [];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var x = [];
  x[0] = 'url ' + i;
  x[1] = function(){};
  x[2] = function(){};
  arrayList.push(x);
}
```

---

#### Edit:

To get the `url` variable used in the `displayFile` call to be specific for each iteration, you need a closure to capture the value:

```
var newArray = new Array();
for(var i=0;i<fileUrls.length;++i) {
  var url = fileUrls[i];
  var x = [];//new Array();

  var f;
  (function(url){
    f = function(){
      displayFile(url, 'image', null, ft_id, null, null, null, null, !MA.isiOS());
    };
  })(url);

  x = [url, f , 
    function(e){
      if(DEBUG) console.log('Error creating gallery thumbnail');
      alert('There was a problem creating a thumbnail');
      MA.hideMessage();
    }
  ];
  newArray.push(x);
}
```

Comment: Let me add an edit so you see more of what i did.... as i believe i did DO the solution you were asking of, and this is still an issue.  I will post the loop i have

Comment: The URL is the correct URL for the variable, in my top example.  The issue is the URL in first function of the array.  Inside, it, it takes URL, which is all the same.  function(){displayFile(url, 'image'...);}  as the same url, but the outter ones are different.

Comment: Is it really the `url` value in the array that is the same in all items? The `url` value used in the `displayFile` call will be the local variable caught in the close for the funtion, so that will be the same for all items. [And you answered that while I was typing.] To get the specific value from each iteration you would need another closure to capture the value of the variable instead of the variable itself. See edit above.